# What was text in final frame of Magi?

Tags: japanese-language, magi

Here is the final frame of episode 25 of *Magi: The Kingdom of Magic*:

[image]

It is the final end card of not just the episode, but the series. It shows after the credits and ending song. The exclamation mark in the text implies to me that it says something like, "Thanks for watching!" or "See you next season!". Since those are guesses, what does it actually say?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is purely a Japanese language question, not related to anime and its content.

Comment: @AkiTanaka ??? Did you not see the picture? It is from an anime, and concerning something related to that anime which non-Japanese speakers could not understand.  If I posted a random picture that someone took while on vacation of a Japanese menu and asked what it said, then yeah, that would be off topic. But this is **from an anime**. My question is primarily about the anime and just happens to involve the Japanese language.  If it were written in Korean or Thai or some in-story code, I'd still ask the same thing. What was the anime staff trying to communicate?

Comment: I'm afraid this is an analogy to what SO called [a boat-programming problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14486/241919): just because the Japanese text is from an anime, then it is considered as anime-related question. However, I may be biased because I more-or-less understand Japanese. I'll leave the decision to the community.

Comment: As far as I know [this meta question](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69/should-we-allow-questions-that-are-about-japanese-language-use-in-anime-manga) is is still the consensus view on Japanese language questions, and the answers disallow this sort of question where a simple direct translation is all that is required and the language is unrelated to any story considerations. As such I agree with @AkiTanaka that this is off-topic.

Comment: @AkiTanaka we have had questions asking about what certain text in an anime says like [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/29974/1587) and [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/27040/1587) but we don't make a habit of being japanese translators. considering that this is an end card i would assume there's no dialog spoken and there's no other visible text so to me it does seem odd for a subtitle so i'm inclined to leave it open though the question could add if this is a subtitle or not and if so if there was english subs though before asking why maybe this is different

Comment: @LoganM As it turned out, once I read the answer, I learned the text did not apply to the anime itself.  But without knowing what it said, how could one possibly conclude that? It could have said, "Next season, Sinbad betrays Aladdin!" Just anything the animation studio wanted its viewers to think about going forward.

Comment: @Memor-X As you surmised, the end card did not contain any audio or English text. // Are you suggesting I add something to the question? It has already been asked and answered, and it seems silly to me closing it is even being discussed. Those who are voting to close it must realize it will quickly fade into obscurity anyway. I appreciate that they have commented on why they voted to close, but the net effect is nil.

Comment: @RichF If the on-screen text happened to say that, it would *still* be off-topic to simply ask for just a translation of it. Questions about understanding the use of Japanese in anime/manga need to be more than pure translation questions; there must be some story-related context required to answer. There are plenty of translation services available which would be more appropriate. In a case like this even [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#ja/en/%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A8%E3%81%86%E3%81%94%E3%81%96%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%EF%BC%81) does a good job.

Comment: @LoganM I guess we'll just have to agree to disagree. I don't know how you can look at that picture and conclude the text has no "story-related context", but apparently you can. Cool. (Further points discussed in a post to the Meta thread you referenced.)

Comment: You are still misunderstanding what I am saying. I did not say that the text has no story-related context. Rather, I said that it does not require any such context to answer your question as asked. You only need to know the literal meaning of the words on screen. That makes it a pure translation question. There may or may not be more to say about the text beyond its literal translation (in this case there is not) but that is not what you asked about.

Comment: A simple test you can use to check this yourself is to ask whether your question would still have any content if the text was written in a language you are fluent in. If the answer is "No", then it is a question for a translator, but not for this site. If, even with that, you do not know if the answer is "No", then it is likely that your question is probably too vague or open-ended. In practice it would be difficult to ask an acceptable question involving Japanese language on this site without at least knowing a bit of Japanese yourself, and that is by design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says "Thanks you very much!" or Arigatō gozaimashita